# Incrementing a bounce variable by one at a time - C++

Tags: c++, increment, projectile

I'm trying to make a simulation of a bouncing ball, one which just spits out the numbers of the x-position, y-position, time and number of bounces. It works perfectly as far as the physics goes, but the problem is that when I try to increment the 'bounces' variable, it increases by one every frame, instead of one, then waiting for the next bounce.

Here's the relevant loop:

```
while(bounces<=maxBounces){
    frames++;
    seconds=frames/1000;    

    if(yPos>=0&&bounces==0){
        initRads=getRads(initAng);
        dropBall(initVel, initRads);    
    }
    if(yPos<0){
        yPos=0;
        bounces++;
        cout.precision(5);
        cout<<seconds<<"\t"<<yPos<<"\t"<<xPos<<"\t"<<bounces<<"\n";
        newVel=getVel(currYVel, currXVel, cor);
        newAng = getAng(currYVel,newVel);

        dropBall(newVel, newAng);
    }   
}
```

Comment: It seems like the only way that will happen is if yPos is less than 0. Is your getAng() working?

Comment: Why does getAng() use velocities? Shouldn't the previous angle be used?

Comment: Also do you only print on the bounce or does dropBall() print. And Sorin makes a good point.

Comment: Right, I've realised that because my getAng() is using the current Y-velocity, instead of the newVel y-component, that's going to throw it off. How would I go about using the previous angle?

Comment: No worries. What I've done is switched it so that it gets the new components, then finds the resultant, then goes for the new angle, but the bouncing problem is still evident. I've tried incrementing as part of dropBall() but the same thing happens (i.e. giving dropBall a param of bounce, which is zero on the first instance and one on the others, which it then adds to the bounce count, but it still doesn't work. So it's <0 for more than one frame somehow, I just don't see how.

Answer (score 1):

Your simulation is a bit wrong. You should have an else branch on if `yPos<0` that does a `dropBall`.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. Could you explain? Sorry, you may have noticed I'm not too hot at this.

Comment: @user2988064 From your code it seems like the ball will only be dropped if it is at the start or if the yPos < 0.

Comment: oh, got you. So should I have the if yPos<0 leading to yPos=0, then else if yPos==0, do the drop?

Comment: @user2988064 you should have if ypos < 0 {...} else dropBall. The init stuff should be outside of the while loop.